# Django Form post method returning error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making a single page chat app which will list all the message I post. The thing is in order to make the list and the form appear in single page, I have to define a single view(from what I understand. I'm pretty new to Django.) that point to  a url. My django files are like this:

## chat/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from chat import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', views.ChatListView.as_view(), name='chat'),
]
```

## chat/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from chat.models import Chat

class NewMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
         attrs={'rows': 3, 'placeholder': 'Type here'}), max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ['message']
```

## chat.html

```
...#some styling codes
    <form method="post" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %} 
                    {{ form }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
                </form>
```

## chat/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from chat.models import Chat
from chat.forms import NewMessageForm

class ChatListView(ListView):
    model = Chat
    template_name = 'chat.html'
    paginate_by = 20

    ##I had a hard time rendering the form in html and this code solves the problem (from a stackoverflow answer)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = NewMessageForm()
        return context

    ##I'm not sure of this code. Am I doing it right?
    def new_message(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewMessageForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('chat')
        else:
            form = NewMessageForm()
        return render(request, 'chat.html', {'form': form})
```

When I run the server the chat.html shows up just fine with the form. But when I submit the form it has a 405 error. Where did I do it wrong?